# Can a PS Plus subscription be used for two profiles?

Tags: ps4, psn

My brother and I got a PS4. we created two separate profiles and found out that for online gaming, PS plus is required.

We can buy a PS Plus subscription for a year but not sure if that subscription will be for both of us? Both accounts have their own PSN accounts.

Can I also transfer a profile from one PSN account to another one?

Comment: My mistake closing this; upon rereading I see it's not the same question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as long as the account being used to redeem the subscription code is set as primary on PS4 settings.

Answer (score -2):

No. Every local profile on the system requires its own subscription in order to play online.

Comment: This is not true. The other answer is correct. I am the primary account in my PS4 and it allows all other users to access online features, regardless of whether they have subscriptions or not.